Why is there no "returnif <expr>" that could replace (and optimize) the pattern "return <expr> if <expr>"
I often find myself typing this pattern for a variety of reasons:
return <expr> if <expr>

Not only does this seem wasteful, but if <expr> has any sort of evaluation time, then it makes more sense to do this:
tmpVar = <expr>
return tmpVar if tmpVar

But it seems silly to have to make a tmpVar just do this, and it's even less readable.  I've always wanted something like this:
returnif <expr>

That returns the expression if it ends up evaluating to a non-nil/false value.
Unfortunately this isn't something that can be easily added to the language from inside of the language because it alters control flow.
Is this that unusual of a request or perhaps that unusual of a pattern for most people?  I'm surprised that neither ruby nor perl seems to have a construct like this yet.
And for extra credit - are there any languages that have this kind of a construct?

Great question. Would you mind adding more context, for example how you usually use such an implicit return in your methods? Because I hardly ever use implicit returns and especially rarely with an if like in your example, and I wonder what your use case looks like in context.

One simple example would be if you have memoization, so at the top you might have:
def someFunc(var1, var2, var3); returnif savedVals[var1][var2][var3]....
But that's just one example.  Maybe it's just my unusual programming style that this pattern comes up a lot, which would explain why I haven't seen what seems like an obvious need - but there are plenty of times where we can return our "calculations" early in some case if there is a simpler answer or a predetermined answer available.

Absolutely reasonable, and it comes up in some guises often I'd expect  (it does for me).   But I don't think  any language would have that?  There surely are libraries but that only hides what you'd like to avoid.

I don't know Ruby but in Perl you can do if (my $r = EXPR) { return $r }, which still does create an extra variable but at least it is scoped (so the rest of the function need not worry) and it runs EXPR only once.  (In most other scripting languages I don't think that one can scope that extra variable)

There are Ruby patterns for what you say. Consider THIS example for memoization. The only difference between return @my_simple_method if defined? @my_simple_method and your example of returnif ... is really just an additional keyword. You can write a macro to make this so if you really want it.

@dawg - see the question again.  That is problematic if '@my_simple_method' is actually an expression that takes time to evaluate.  Also, I don't know of any way to create a macro that can change control flow and do a return like this.  Please elucidate an example.

@zdim - you can't really do this with a "simple" library, since a library can't call "return" on the caller scope.

@DavidLjungMadisonStellar: The pattern shown means that @my_simple_method is only done once.

@dawg right.  And that's not the question here.  The question here is what if we want to do "return  if " where presumably  is more than just an instance variable lookup.

Please don't tag multiple languages. Different languages can have and do have very different answers. If you want to Ruby constructs, ask that. If you want Perl constructs, ask that. If you want both, ask both. But don't merge two questions together to make it unanswerable.

@engineersmnky  Don't re-add incorrect tags.

@ikegami There is nothing incorrect about it in my opinion. The post clearly asks about perl, includes a perl answer, and return <expr> if <expr> is a perl idiom so [tag:perl] seems appropriate. Additionally when the tag was removed the only reasonable answer was a answer in perl, in which case [tag:ruby] should have been removed. While I understand your sentiment of asking a separate question per language, it seems the perl community is the only one that has a problem with both tags and in my opinion the removal damages the resulting answer.

Actually return <expr> if <expr> is really a ruby idiom, because it would be return <expr> if <expr>; if it was perl.  :-)
I was intentionally asking about both, and about high level languages in general.  Those just happen to be the languages I know best.  Sorry if that makes you unhappy @ikegami, I see no reason to limit such questions on here.

This was tough to pick an answer on - there were some great options, and I was blown away by the catch throw extend ruby answer, but I think @Ry- had the answer that was the most comprehensive, even if it did usually use a temp variable, which I was trying explicitly to avoid.

Re "Actually return  if  is really a ruby idiom", Why do you imply I said otherwise? /// Re "I was intentionally asking about both", Again, that's wrong. If you have different questions, ask different questions. /// Re "I see no reason to limit such questions on here", Lots of reason. First of all, there's the rules. But aside from that, the site focuses on questions that can be answered by a single question. Asking multiple questions with different answers encourages different answers to answer different questions. (And that's exactly what happened.)


Unfortunately this isn't something that can be easily added to the language from inside of the language because it alters control flow.

This particular control flow can be done from blocks in Ruby, though:
def guard(x)
  yield x if x
end

guard(expensive.operation) { return _1 }
# or `return it` in 3.4+


Is this that unusual of a request or perhaps that unusual of a pattern for most people? I'm surprised that neither ruby nor perl seems to have a construct like this yet.
And for extra credit - are there any languages that have this kind of a construct?

Many languages have the potential for some kind of similar guard pattern, although it usually involves a variable. That’s because what you’re asking for just isn’t that common as a need, especially compared to the opposite (returning nil when a value is nil – see try/? operators). They include…
Rust
if let Some(x) = expensive_operation() {
    return x;
}

or functionally,
expensive_operation().or_else(continuation)

Go
if x := expensiveOperation(); x != nil {
    return x
}

Swift
if let x = expensiveOperation() {
    return x
}

Haskell
import Control.Applicative (Alternative (..))

expensive_operation <|> continuation

(and probably some do-notation option I’m not aware of)
Python
if (x := expensive_operation()):
    return x

C#
if (ExpensiveOperation() is Foo x) {
    return x;
}

JavaScript
expensiveOperation() ?? continuation()
// or || for falsy values

I can keep expanding this, but you get the point.

I mean..  the yield/guard trick is pretty clever, although syntactically a bit gross and not particularly readable.  Most of the other examples that don't use continuations are just using a temp var, as I pointed out was possible in my OP.  The hope here is to come up with something that is not just efficient, but readable and clean.

@DavidLjungMadisonStellar: A temporary variable is readable and clean in the languages I listed – all of them support a pattern that’s about as specific as possible for doing what you need (while still being more general, since like I said – very niche need), and they all do it by binding the non-nil value to a name.

I wasn't saying it wasn't clean - but having to save the value to a temp variable first seems like unnecessary cruft considering it's going to be used once and only once, right away.  If anything, the potential answer could be calculated in the return area of the stack.  Compilers/interpreters are regularly saving us from having to use unnecessary one-time temp variables, with even just how we do complex expressions, like (a * b + c * d), which will have at least one temp variable needed to evaluate.

Since Perl was mentioned, if ( my $x = expensive_operation() ) { return $x } and expensive_operation() || continuation() (incl expensive_operation() || do { continuation(); })

How about using the lowly || with a begin/end block?
return <expr> || begin
  <continuation>
end


That is a really neat idea - though it does mean adding another layer of scope when it's not really necessary, since nothing can happen after that scope.  Neat idea though.

If a secondary closure is an option then we could easily implement def return_if(x,&block) = x || block.call(x) usage as return_if(x) do but it really only works as a guard clause and not really maintainable at depth in my opinion.

One way to implement such a thing in Perl, using the Macro::Simple module found on CPAN:
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.36;
use Macro::Simple {
  'returnif($)' => '{ my $val = %s; return $val if $val; }'
};

sub demo($val) {
  returnif($val == 0); # The parenthesis are required
  return "not zero";
}

say demo(1);
say demo(0);



are there any languages that have this kind of a construct?

Maybe not built in, but it can be easy to write it using other features of a language, like macros. Some examples:
Tcl:
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc returnif {exp} {
    # Evaluate in the caller's scope
    set val [uplevel 1 [list expr $exp]]
    if {$val} {
        # -level 2 makes the caller of this proc return $val
        return -level 2 $val
    }
}

proc demo {val} {
    returnif {$val == 0}
    return "not zero"
}

puts [demo 1]
puts [demo 0]

Common Lisp:
(defmacro returnif-from (name expr)
  "Return the result of evaluating expr from the named block if that value is true"
  (let ((gval (gensym)))
    `(let ((,gval ,expr)) (when ,gval (return-from ,name ,gval)))))
(defmacro returnif (expr)
  "Return the result of evaluating expr from the current nil block if that value is true"
  `(returnif-from nil ,expr))

(defun demo (val)
  (returnif-from demo (= val 0))
  "not zero")

(format t "~A~%" (demo 1))
(format t "~A~%" (demo 0))


Not extensively tested, and there very well might be a module that provides a better way to extend the language out there.

Hah, didn't know about this!  As bad as macros may be this is useful to have

That's interesting - I am going to take a guess that Macro::Simple is a perl filter that edits the code before running it?  I suppose that is definitely one possibility - though I don't think ruby has any such capabilities.

Ruby perspective.
Commentary
My initial concern in reading the question is that return if x or return unless y are typical idioms as guard clauses, which appears to be what you are expressing in your comment (a guard clause that is).
returnif x and return if x could be very confusing at they would have precisely opposite effects, given that the first would return x if it is "truthy" and the second will return nil if x is "truthy".
All that being said I could see a use case for this (although I think naming might be an issue as described above, I proposed return_if below but I still dislike it), so maybe open a feature request here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/ and see how others feel about it.
As you mentioned this could be better optimized if it was implemented at a lower level as a keyword similar to return.
Possible Solution

Unfortunately this isn't something that can be easily added to the language from inside of the language because it alters control flow.

This is not entirely accurate and while I am not recommending this, we can use the throw/catch control flow along with some awful meta-programming to simulate the requested functionality.
This works because when calling Kernel#throw "...Ruby searches up its stack for a catch block..", so it does not matter where in the call stack throw is called as long as somewhere above it there is a matching catch.
We can leverage this knowledge by wrapping every new method definition in a catch block and then use a defined method return_if to call the corresponding throw when the condition is true.
module ReturnIf 
  def self.extended(base)
    base.include(InstanceMethods)
  end 

  def method_added(method_name)
    return if @_adding 
    @_adding = true 
    original_method = instance_method(method_name)
    define_method(method_name) do |*args,**kwargs,&block|
      Kernel.catch(:__short_circuit__) {original_method.bind(self).call(*args,**kwargs,&block)}
    end
  ensure 
    @_adding = false
  end 

  def singleton_method_added(method_name)
    return if @_adding
    @_adding = true
    original_method = method(method_name) 
    define_singleton_method(method_name) do |*args,**kwargs,&block| 
      Kernel.catch(:__short_circuit__) {original_method.call(*args,**kwargs,&block)}
    end
  ensure 
    @_adding = false
  end 
  module InstanceMethods
    def return_if(x)
      return_now(x) if x
    end
    def return_unless(x) 
      return_now unless x
    end   
    def return_now(x=nil) 
      Kernel.throw(:__short_circuit__,x)
    end 
  end
end 

BasicObject.extend(ReturnIf)

Now every method added to an object will be wrapped in this control flow which allows you to use return_[if/unless/now] <expr> in any method body.
Example:
class A
  def self.testing(x)
    return_if x
    42
  end 
  def self.t_block(x)
    return_if yield x if block_given? 
    42 
  end 
  def testing(x)
    return_if x 
    42 
  end 
end
A.testing(2) 
#=> 2 
A.testing(nil)
#=> 42
A.t_block(nil) 
#=> 42 
A.t_block(nil) {|e| e.nil?} 
#=> true
A.new.testing(2) 
#=> 2 
A.new.testing(nil)
#=> 42


Okay - that's a clever use of extend that I hadn't even considered.  I do think you and I can both agree that it would probably be an 'extreme' choice to accomplish the change in the language, but it definitely works.  I kind of want to accept this as a proper answer even though it's only for Ruby.

@DavidLjungMadisonStellar if this were a real language feature it should absolutely be implemented in the interpreter as a keyword. This was merely offered as a proof of concept because I love "I don't think you can do it in ruby" questions. Also this does allow you to isolate the functionality. I extended BasicObject because you wanted it throughout the language but you could just extend A to limit scope (kind of like a refinement), just make sure it's the first line after the class declaration, otherwise I'd have to add functionality to redefine all existing methods...
